# Log visits in shared memory

Tags: php, logging, nginx, memcached, apc

I'm trying to find best way to log visits using PHP. Right now I have about 3000 request per second and I write each visit to CSV file. I was wondering is it faster to log each visit in memory somehow and then dump it to CSV file after 100 000 records? I've checked `shmop` `apc` and `memcache` so far but can't find proper solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way is to use Lua with shared memory to store log entries, then create a timer which checks the size of logged entries every X seconds and uses a co-socket to dump the cache to a file or sql database. Should all be non-blocking. And yes you can pass requests to Lua before passing it to PHP.
You could also use nginx default logfile caching(buffer) and parse the logs separately.